# (char)NULL , '\0' and 0 all mean the same thing in C's memset?

Tags: linux, c

We are migrating a 32 bit application from rhel 5.3 to 6.4

We are getting an warning "Cast from pointer to integer of different size " on new system's `memset`.

Do `(char)NULL`, `'\0'` and `0` all mean the same thing in C's memset?

The following code is giving the warning in new environment.

```
#define NULLC  (char)NULL
#define MAX_LEN  11 
…
memset(process_name, NULLC, MAX_LEN + 1);
strncpy(process_name, "oreo", MAX_LEN);
```

Comment: Post the line(s) of code that are causing trouble. Karlson has provided a correct answer, but it might not help you because you didn't post the relevant code.

Comment: The following code is giving the warning in new environment.

#define NULLC  (char)NULL

#define MAX_LEN  11 

memset(process_name, NULLC, MAX_LEN + 1);


strncpy(process_name, "oreo", MAX_LEN);

Comment: Any reason to define `NULLC` as `(char)NULL`?

Comment: [Be careful with `strncpy()`](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html); it very likely doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The do *not* all mean the same thing, though they're likely to yield the same result.

`(char)NULL` converts the value of `NULL`, which is an implementation-defined null pointer constant, to `char`. The type of `NULL` may be `int`, or `void*`, or some other integer type. If it's of an integer type, the conversion is well defined and yields `0`. If it's `void*`, you're converting a *null pointer* value to `char`, which has an implementation-defined result (which is likely, but not guaranteed, to be 0).

The macro `NULL` is intended to refer to a null *pointer* value, not a null *character*, which is a very different thing.

Your macro `NULLC` is not particularly useful. If you want to refer to a null character, just use the literal constant `'\0'`. (And `NULLC` is IMHO too easily confused with `NULL`.)

The other two constants, `'\0'` and `0`, have exactly the same type (`int`) and value (zero).

(It's admittedly counterintutive that `'\0'` has type `int` rather than `char`. It's that way for historical reasons, and it rarely matters. In C++, character constants are of type `char`, but you asked about C.)

Answer (score 6):

They all have the same value `0` but they don't mean the same thing.

```
(char)NULL  - You are casting the value of NULL pointer to character with value 0
'\0'        - End of string character with value 0 (NUL)
0           - 32 bit integer with value 0.
```

You are getting a warning because somewhere in your code you're likely using something like:

```
short somevar = NULL;
```

or something similar.

Comment: The standard does NOT guarantee that "NULL" is represented as 0, though essentially all modern systems do. So '\0' and 0 are the same thing (the type of a character literal is actually int), but NULL might be different.

Answer (score 3):

`0` and `'\0'` are both the integer 0 (the type of a character literal is `int`, not `char`), so they are exactly equivalent. The second argument to memset is an int, from which only the low-order 8 bits will be used.

NULL is a different beast. It is a pointer type that is guaranteed by the standard to be different from any pointer to a real object. The standard does *NOT* say that this is done by giving it the value 0, though it must compare equal to zero. Also, it may be of different width than `int`, so passing it as the second argument to `memset()` might not compile.

Comment: Basically correct, but imprecisely worded. "Integer" is a more general term than `int`. your first sentence seems to conflate them. The low-order `CHAR_BIT` bits of the second argument to `memset` are used; more precisely, the `int` value is converted to `unsigned char`. `NULL` is not a "pointer type"; it's a macro that expands to an implementation-defined *null pointer constant". The relative widths of a pointer and `int` are irrelevant to whether a call to `memset` will compile or not; that's determined by the types of the arguments, not their sizes.

Comment: The type of `NULL` is implementation-defined (either `void*` or some integer type), but it's always legal to cast it to `char` -- though it doesn't make sense to do so.

Comment: No, NULL is not always 0. `(void*)0` must evaluate to NULL, and comparing a pointer with 0 must do the same thing as comparing it to NULL, but NULL does not have to be actually internally represented as 0, and some systems actually do exist that use a different one. Keith, NULL might be a `long`, and calling `memset` with a long second argument (without casting it) can error out, can it not?

Comment: An argument of any numeric type will be implicitly converted to `int`. (As long as the declaration is visible; if it isn't, the call is invalid anyway in C99 and higher.) You might get a warning in some cases, but a conforming compiler cannot reject the program for that reason. Calling `memset` with a second argument of `NULL` is a constraint violation (and may "error out") if `NULL` is of type `void*`.

Comment: "*No, NULL is not always 0.*" -- Who said it was? "*`(void*)0` must evaluate to `NULL`*" -- More precisely, both `(void*)0` and `NULL` must evaluate to a null pointer value.

Comment: Yes, I'm being a bit imprecise. I'm sure we both understand the issues here, we're just disagreeing on how to explain it to someone who doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In defining NULLC, you are casting `NULL` from a native pointer (64-bits, probably defined as `(void*)0`) to `char` (8-bits). If you wanted to declare NULLC, you should just do

```
#define NULLC 0
```

and do away with `NULL` and the `(char)`. The formal argument to `memset` is `int`, not `char`.

Answer (score 0):

```
0 = zero of int datatype
'\0' = (char)0  //null char
NULL = (void*)0 //null pointer
```

See how they are interlinked to each other. Gcc often gives warnings for all the typecast that are implicitly done by the compiler.

You are using

```
#define NULLC (char)NULL
.....
memset(process_name, NULLC, MAX_LEN + 1);
```

equivalent to:

```
memset(process_name, (char)NULL, MAX_LEN + 1);
```

equivalent to:

```
memset(process_name, '\0', MAX_LEN + 1);
```

You are passing char data (ie; `'\0'` ) as second parameter where "unsigned int" data is accepted. So compiler is converting it to unsigned int implicilty and thus giving typecast warning. You can simply ignore it or change it as:

```
memset(process_name, 0, MAX_LEN + 1);
```